# How to add access property and wrap the arguments with curly brackets with regex in js?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings. Each string might contain function calls.

I made this regular expression to match the word between `$ctrl.` and `(`, as long as it is immediately after `$ctrl.` and it will also match the parameters inside the parentheses if they exist.

```
/(\$ctrl\.)(\w+)(\(([^)]+)\))?/g;
```

Once there is a match then I add `emit` before the function call (`$ctrl.foo()` to `$ctrl.foo.emit()`), and if there are brackets then I wrap them with curly brackets: `$ctrl.foo(account, user)` to `$ctrl.foo.emit({ account, user })`).

The problem is this regex doesn't work for some cases.

```js
const inputs = [
  '$ctrl.foo(account)',
  '$ctrl.foo(account, bla)',
  '$ctrl.foo(account, bla); $ctrl.some()',
  '$ctrl.foo(account, bla);$ctrl.some(you)',
  '$ctrl.foo.some(account, bla);$ctrl.fn.some(you)',
  '$ctrl.gog',
];

const regex = /(\$ctrl\.)(\w+)(\(([^)]+)\))?/g;

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  let output = input.replace(regex, '$1$2.emit({$4})');
  console.log(output);
});
```

The results:

```
$ctrl.foo.emit({account})
$ctrl.foo.emit({account, bla})
$ctrl.foo.emit({account, bla}); $ctrl.some.emit({})()
$ctrl.foo.emit({account, bla});$ctrl.some.emit({you})
$ctrl.foo.emit({}).some(account, bla);$ctrl.fn.emit({}).some(you)
$ctrl.gog.emit({})
```

The first and two results are excellent. The regex adds `emit` and wraps the arguments with `{..}`.

But the regex is not working if I don't have arguments or if I have another access property before the function call: `$ctrl.foo.bar()` (should not match this case).

What is missing in my regex to get those results?

```
$ctrl.foo.emit({account})
$ctrl.foo.emit({account, bla})
$ctrl.foo.emit({account, bla}); $ctrl.some.emit()
$ctrl.foo.emit({account, bla});$ctrl.some.emit({you})
$ctrl.foo.some(account, bla);$ctrl.fn.some(you)
$ctrl.gog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this modified regexp works better for you?

```js
const inputs = [
  '$ctrl.foo(account)',
  '$ctrl.foo(account, bla)',
  '$ctrl.foo(account, bla); $ctrl.some()',
  '$ctrl.foo(account, bla);$ctrl.some(you)',
  '$ctrl.foo.some(account, bla);$ctrl.fn.some(you)',
  '$ctrl.gog',
];

const regex = /(\$ctrl\.)(\w+)(\(([^)]*)\))/g;

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  let output = input.replace(regex, '$1$2.emit({$4})');
  console.log(output);
});
```

I changed two quantifies in the regexp:

- `[^)]+` to `[^)]*` this allows also zero-length matches
- `)?/g` to `)/g` this makes the existence of the `\( ... \)`-group at the end of the pattern no longer optional but compulsory.